# In linux, cannot kill sleep processes (trash.so or dolphin). what to do?

Tags: linux, process, sleep

I cant kill any sleep process. I have tried most of the kill signals.

I confront this problem often. What i must do in order to kill these processes?

```
trap "kill -15 '-773623'" 0 1 2 3 15
```

It says killed but process is still there.

[linux output](https://ibb.co/KVtq38J)

update

```
(base) root@eliasc:/# 
(base) root@eliasc:/# ps axo stat,ppid,pid,comm | grep -w defunct | awk '{print $2}'
1
738680
738680
(base) root@eliasc:/# kill -9 738680
(base) root@eliasc:/# sudo kill -9 738680
(base) root@eliasc:/# ps axo stat,ppid,pid,comm | grep -w defunct | awk '{print $2}'
1
738680
738680
(base) root@eliasc:/#
```

Comment: Have you try `kill -9 PID`? And using negative numbers as PID in `kill` can have unpredictable results

Comment: Nothing..... i have sent  lot kill signals from htop.... nothing... i killed and restarted parent process plasmashell... nothing...

Comment: Have you try from command line as `root`?

Comment: see updated output

Comment: I poweroff myHDD... and system is ok. How i can mount / remount on the fly an HDD?

Comment: Yes, reboot is the main way (in Linux)

Comment: For other question please ask new one.

Answer (score 1):

From what I see there process are defunct, not sleep. AFAIK there is tool to "kill" defunct (zombie) processes in Solaris. But I am not sure there is such tool in Linux.

If you reboot the machine they will disappear.

Comment: The aim is to remove them without restart

Comment: @EliasEstatistics, there is no way (no utility to do it). And they usually do not mess much the OS :)

Comment: @RomeoNinov Killing the parent process should do it. And if it is owned by the init process, then it should be reaped automatically.

Comment: @RomeoNinov i am looking for alternate solutions like "umount trash" or something similar.... something that indirectly will interrupt such cases. Also, i killed / restarted plasma (as parent process). All processes "D" went to init, plasma restarted normally (without computer restart). Nothing really changed.

Comment: @EliasEstatistics, there is NO SUCH THING as "umount trash" And as I wrote restart is the solution. Or wait, sometime they disappear over the time

Answer (score 0):

The `D` state letter means "uninterruptible sleep, usually Input/Output operations".  When you have a lot of processes in the `D` state like in your picture, it typically means **your disk is failing**.

The "defunct" state (also known as the "zombie" state) would be indicated by letter `Z` instead.

Run `sudo dmesg` and you might see a lot of device I/O error messages in the output.

Make sure you have a backup of any important data on a different disk.

Comment: The disk is very new (some months old). I had many operations on the disk: Downloading files, ffmpeg files, saving files... AND deleting files on the same time. I am a multitasking person :P Note that i have a usb HUB with 8 HDD on it and there are switches on/off which help me to interrupt these D states.