# In linux, processes went "D" caused of HDD problem. How to interrupt D processes without going on/off the HDD?

Tags: linux, process

In linux, processes went "D" caused of HDD problem (some kernel calls were mixed?).
How I can interrupt D processes without going on/off my HDD?
These processes were trash.so / dolphin mainly (most of times). I turned my HDD off and then processes continued from "D" state.
It is not server, it is home computer.

I have this problem in KDE many times now.

Any other idea except manipulating hardware external to:

- Interrupt Trash process
- Throught terminal to mount on/off HDD on the fly
- To umount trash?
- To sent fake signals to Trash?
- To rewrite linux?
- Other ideas?

I have not a working example...

- "D State" = “uninterruptible non-scheduled” state -  the process cannot be interrupted
- Unmount trash - I think in linux many things are mounted... how u get rid of trash temporarily as a whole? eg. unmount trash?
  (So maybe i can this way to interrupt uninterrupted processes).

Comment: what does "umount trash" mean? What is "sent signals to Trash"? I thought trash was something you can mount? What is a "fake signal" ? I'm also not sure what a "D process" is – could you explain?

Comment: I guess by "D" process the OP means a process whose state is indicated as "D" (uninterruptible sleep) by tools like `top` or `ps`. This state usually indicates a process that is "hanging" on access to device, due to hardware failure. I also wondered many times how to terminate such a process.

Comment: @MarcusMüller, the OP mean defunct process https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/711485/in-linux-cannot-kill-sleep-processes-trash-so-or-dolphin-what-to-do/711491?noredirect=1#comment1347262_711491

Comment: Updated my question... yes Uninterrupted processes mean. When get HDD off, processes continue and i like to do this in a softer way... it exists?

Comment: @RomeoNinov oh! Then we should really remove the [tag:sleep] tag, nothing about this is [tag:sleep]!

Comment: @EliasEstatistics you're really using the word "mount" incorrectly. This has nothing to do with *mounts*, which is a Linux term pertaining to folder structures and block devices, not to processes. Please try to find a different description of what you want to do.

Comment: @RomeoNinov following the [tag:zombie-process] pattern, the tag should be [defunct-process], but I don't see why defunct processes even need a tag.

Comment: @muru, AFAIK defunct is the word used in kernel documentation. I see zombie mostly in UNIX documentation. Maybe you are right, it may be defunct-process